# Perl fastest way to serve static file

Tags: perl, file, printing, static

I have a perl cgi script that I'm running where occasionally I need to serve a static HTML file to the user. Is there a more efficient way to do this than just reading in the file and printing it out line by line? Right now I do:

```
print while(<$file>);
```

I know there are modules like File::Slurp that can be used for efficient reading, but I wasn't sure if I'd see any performance gain from this. Is there a good way in perl to serve out a static file completely? Or is just regular printing the best?

Comment: It would be fastest if you let your webserver serve the file directly.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, thanks. Unfortunately I'm updating somebody else's system, and this is the way the code is expected to work so I have to handle it this way.

Comment: The way you're doing it is probably about as fast as it's going to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing larger blocks than one line at a time might be faster, and so might

```
exec("cat", "--", $path)
```

But why is CGI being used to server static files in the first place???

Comment: That's a good question! I'm updating an old system and CGI was used sometimes serve dynamic content, and sometimes place pure static content onto the webpage. I'm not sure why it was done that way.